# Como proibir o download de arquivo e deixar somente a visualização?

Tags: php, html

Tenho um arquivo, exemplo: um filme "Os vingadores.mp4" e eu quero somente que o publico visualize, mas caso alguém tente acessar para baixar não seja permitido fazer o download.

Comment: Tentando criar uma versão do megafilmesHD? :p Brincadeiras a parte, creio que não seja possivel, se você permite que seja tocado online, o conteudo precisa ser baixado para que possa ser tocado. Há formas de dificultar, como criptografia(nextflix usa esse recurso), [Memory Stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609018/writing-to-stream-without-file-path) so c# que bufferiza na memoria do client sem salvar arquivo fisico, dentre outros. Mas é praticamente impossivel impedir que alguem consiga reproduzir o conteudo.

Comment: tenta colocar o filme em um servidor separado, e colocar uma politica de acesso só pro ip onde o teu site vai esta hospedado, assim se alguem tentar seguir o link  aonde o teu filme vai ta hospedado vai dar um erro *503*. nunca testei não mas acho que funfa.

Comment: Eu nunca usei, então não vou me arriscar a escrever a respeito, mas o padrão W3C pra isso é o [Encrypted Media Extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypted_Media_Extensions).

Comment: Qualquer coisa que tentar não vai funcionar. No máximo poderá dificultar. Mas mesmo dificultando com códigos mirabolantes, o usuário ainda terá o audio e video no stream. Então basta dar play e usar um gravador de  stream. Já era. Tudo em vão. Só funcionaria se vc puder ter controle do aplicativo cliente.